# Unity 3d no puedo establecer diferente orientacion por cada escena

Tags: unity3d, unity

Estoy haciendo un juego en Unity y quiero establecer una orientacion diferente por cada escena(portrait landscape).

No me deja hacerlo.

1-Cuando lo pongo por codigo no me hace caso:

`if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "1Scena"){ Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait; }`

2-Cuando lo pongo en el GameView si lo cambio en una me lo cambia en todas.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y añadas el código de lo que has intentado a tu pregunta, así como resultados que has obtenidos y/o errores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente tu pregunta es confusa, Screen.orientation solo es relevante para la orientación que va a tener la pantalla al jugar al juego, vertical, horizontal, etc.

Pero realmente esta función es únicamente relevante si tu juego es para móvil y quieres cambiarla, porque en ordenador esto no es muy útil, en la documentación ya lo explica https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenOrientation.html

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es cambiar la resolución de la pantalla dependiendo de la escena puedes usar Screen.SetResolution(int width, int height, bool fullscreen);

Te dejo la documentación: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html

**Ten en cuenta que ni lo tuyo, ni esto funcionan en tiempo de ejecución de unity, solo funcionarán cuando compiles el juego y lo pruebes, y de ser eso lo que querías, es por eso que no ves cambios.**

Si resulta que lo que quieres, no era nada de lo anterior, sino cambiar la vista en si del juego, en el sentido de cambiar de isométrica a perspectiva, por ejemplo, ya es cuestión de modificar la posición y la proyección de la cámara (perspectiva u ortográfica).

Accediendo al obeto Camera.main para especificar que es la camara principal (si tienes otras tienes que referenciarlas), y cambiando su proyección con la propiedad orthographic, e incluso su posición y rotación con respecto al personaje o lo que sea que quieras enfocar.

Para que te hagas una idea:

```
Camera.main.transform ...
Camera.main.rotation ...
Camera.main.orthographic = true; 
//camera orthographic (true) or perspective (false)
```

Te dejo las referencias para que veas claramente como se usa, y todo lo que puedes hacer:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html